# Eclipse unable to install Genymotion Plugin Issue

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, genymotion

I am using Eclipse Kepler and installed `genymotion` with virtual box.

When I tried to install `genymotion` plugin for Eclipse (Help->Install New Software), its showing me the following error:

Unable to read repository at https://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/content.xml.
`hostname` in certificate didn't match:

I am using the following link to add plugin as given in `genymotion` website
https://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this address: http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/

Without the https.

Comment: This really worked, but https:// was given in genymotion website, why it didn't work. https:// was working fine with Luna and Mars though

Comment: Where is the https URL? I checked and I didn't find it. If you give it to me we will be able to fix it.

Comment: https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/download


You can see the https:// link in "To install Genymotion plugin for Eclipse:" section. Its working with some versions of eclipse through.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to remove all available links of Genymotion  from "Available Software Sites"

Then use below link as new Software install:

http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse/

Now you see same error :

> error : there is no categorized items

so uncheck Group items by category in the Available software menu?

Now category shown for Genymotion

Answer (score 0):

Removing all `Genymotion` links then Unchecked Group Items worked for me. ***Troubleshoot total estimate time = <30 sec***